# При прокрутке RecyclevView, скролл бар меняется в размере, как пофиксить?

Tags: recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

При прокрутке RecyclerView состоящего из разных элементов разного размера,скролл бар справа изменяется в размере, это можно пофиксить?

Comment: При задании вопрос следует прилагать код и скрины.

Comment: Самый стандартный RecyclerView c элементами  разных размеров.